# Can Existing MySQL Query Be Modified?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query early in a script that sets a limit.

Example:

```
$row = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
```

The "5" is always correct - but there's a plugin I'm building that needs to change the limit from "5" to "2" (a one-off special circumstance).

I can change $row to a new query, before the function to get the result is called - but I'd rather change the existing query.

Something like:

```
$row .= "LIMIT 2"
```

Or:

```
$row += "LIMIT 2"
```

Or:

```
$row < "LIMIT 2"
```

Of course none of those work - It's probably not possible as the query is set - but it can't hurt to ask.

Thanks all

---

Just a quick note - these are two separate files. File A sets the correct query based on environment and houses the function that uses the query.. File B calls the function which outputs the query (therefore I can change the query before the function call in File B). Yes, there's a reason it's setup this way.

Comment: If you want reduce $row, you can do it in reading loop, if performance is not important and `2` and `5` in your real code are so close to each other!

Comment: "5" is a var that the user can set to a high number (5 is just the default). The plugin just needs the first two rows. When you say 'reading loop' do you mean a while()?

Comment: yes I called `while(){}` the reading loop which used to fetch rows one by one... @user3925824

Comment: @MohaMad - ahh, ok. It's possible reading loop is something I've never heard of so I had to ask. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track but you have to change the query string before feeding it in the function. So make a variable for it

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC ";
```

Then, however you wish, make something that adds that limit to this. In my example, an *if* statement

```
if ($this == "this") {
  $query .= "LIMIT 5";
} else {
  $query .= "LIMIT 2";
}
```

And then feed it to mysqli

```
$row = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

**EDIT**

I read your note and your comment. Since you're calling the function from two different files, you can add a default parameter like:

```
function yourFunction($limit = 5) {
  $query = "SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT " . $this;
  $row = mysqli_query($db, $query);
}
```

By default, just calling `yourFunction()` without any parameters, it will do the default, in your case 5.

In that special case where you want a limit of 2, just call the function with that 2 as the parameter.

```
yourFunction(); // This will do the limit of 5

yourFunction(2); // This will do 2
```

This also make is a free-for-all so you can use whatever limit you want

Comment: Yes - normally that would work - but I don't want to change the core application (this is a plugin). For instance I can't say "To use this plugin you just have to change a query in the config file." Though I wrote them both, I want the core application to stay solid (it's already dynamic from the user's perspective) - and I want the plugin to be the oddball.

Comment: While I accepted the answer - the actual answer is it's not possible the way I described in the OP. For future readers, the "5" in this case is pagination number - a particular theme needs only the first two results to show on the front page, remaining lists adhere to the user's preferences - so before the function to get the paginated results, I can rewrite the query with LIMIT 2 (as it occurs in the index). I probably should of explained all that lol - thanks again all

Comment: Your edit wasn't showing after you typed 'see edit', but I see it now. You are correct - I could of added options for that function but didn't think of it. The function already pulls in all the user's settings which can be changed design wise before the function call - so I thought I was good. I didn't think of a case like I'm facing now.. duh. The core's already published - I'll fix it in the next release.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Also, what's your plugin? I'd love to check it out

Answer (score 2):

You can define the limit as a variable in File A:

```
// Define variable
$limit_number = 5;
```

Then include File A in File B using the include function (I assume you are already doing this.)
Then change the value of the variable from File B as it is now available in File B after having included File A in File B.

```
include('path/to/fileA');
$limit_number = 2;
// call the query executing function you speak of from File A.
```

For this to work, you would have to replace the hardcoded `5` as limit to the variable in your query.

```
$row = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$limit_number);
```

Comment: Ok. I didn't think it was possible.. The 5 is a default that the user can change to a high number. The plugin uses the same query but only needs the first two results. I can just change the var before the function gets it - but it doesn't seem the most efficient - seems like two queries are ran with one fetching the result.. but this is a one off plugin, so no biggie. I gotta accept the first guy that responded but I gave a vote up..  I'm assuming the direct answer is it's not possible the way I described.

Comment: There are no 2 queries being executed, or even being declared or having instances at any given time. Only the variable is changed and used by the exact same query. Nevertheless, from the case you are describing, you need exactly what eeetee described after his edit above.

Comment: Yep - his edit was showing for me when I replied to him, but yes - that would be the correct implementation and I'll probably fixed it the next release!